# Select list item alternative field value if target field value is null

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Code for selecting target field value ('targetField'):

```
result = someList.stream()
   .filter(i -> i.geFilterField() == someValue)
   .map(i -> i.getTargetField())
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(null);
```

But 'targetFiled' is nullable.
How can i get value from alternative field (some 'alterField') if target field value is null?

Comment: would  `.map(i -> i.getTargetField() == null ? i.getOtherField() : i.getTargetField())` work (instead of your current map)

Comment: Can't you just do
`.map(i -> i.getTargetField() == null ? i.getAlterField() : i.getTargetField())`

Comment: add `.filter(i -> i.getTargetField() != null)` on row 3

Comment: Or `Optional.ofNullable(i.getTargetField()).orElse(i.getAlterField())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Optional#ofNullable` could be an option here

```
result = someList.stream()
                 .filter(i -> i.geFilterField() == someValue)
                 .map(i -> Optional.ofNullable(i.getTargetField())
                                   .orElse(i.getAlterField()))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to extract the alternative value from the object then it can be done as follows:

```
someList.stream()
   .filter(i -> i.geFilterField() == someValue)
   .map(i -> i.getTargetField() != null ? i.getTargetField() : i.getAlterField())
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the first item only, filter the "raw" items, and then pick the field when you have only one object, like this:

```
tmp = someList.stream()
   .filter(i -> i.geFilterField() == someValue && (i.getTargetField() != null || i.getAlterField() != null))
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(null);
// At this point tmp is either null if nothing is found, or
// it is an object with one or both target fields set to non-null values
result = null;
if (tmp != null) {
    result = tmp.getTargetField() != null ? tmp.getTargetField() : tmp.getAlterField();
}
```